# Related to anchor boxes’s positions

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I’m new to DNN.
Is assuming anchor boxes’s positions when training an object detection model similar to initializing kernels with default weights in CNN?

I’m a beginner to Deep Neural Networks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the idea of initializing anchor boxes and kernels with default weights in a DNN model are similar. In both cases, the idea is to provide a starting point for the model to learn from, rather than starting with a completely random set of values.

If you are using a custom dataset then you can create anchor boxes from several website those are bellow:
https://www.makesense.ai/ 
https://roboflow.com/

In case you used a dataset from Kaggle then there declare the boxed in the training file and you have to calculate anchor boxed from there.

This just a reminder for each object it has 5 values

> class, the center of x and y, width and height